# Showing null on jsp page after ajax call in struts 2 application if hosted on Amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, amazon-web-services, struts2

I found that in my struts 2 application, if I host it on amazon elastic beanstalk, after a few hours, ajax calls wont work and it shows null on jsp page as it gets null value for java object on page.

If I refresh the URL everything starts working again.

Also found that this is due to changed JSESSIONID.
[No problem with session as I kept it alive]

My question is how to handle this problem, I can check for null but my application wont work as ajax calls fail, and I am not able to trace why it is changing JSESSIONID and when? Please advise.

Comment: How many instances are of EC2 are getting generated. You may want to look at session persistence across tomcat(s) using redix / mysql or dynamo db  --OR--- enable session stickiness on the load balancer

Comment: Thank you Sanket.
Only one instance is generated right now and we are not using any Database as we have separate search engine which communicate with application. I will look into your suggestion to session stickiness.